# upload videos from the internal/external SD card

Tags: android

I have decided to develop an application.
What I would like to do is to enable users to upload videos from his phone's internal/external SD card when he/she clicks the upload button.
After the video gets uploaded . I want to show them so that others can play that video in his/her phone.

Comment: Which website you will upload? Youtube?

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the open source project `YouTube Direct Lite for Android` [here](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android).

The code is a reference implementation for an Android OS application that captures video, uploads it to YouTube, and submits the video to a YouTube Direct Lite instance.

There are lots of detail in their [ReadMe](https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-android/blob/master/README.md)